# Make a Powershell function work correctly as both Pipeline and normal invocation

Tags: powershell, pipeline

Say I have the following Powershell function:

```
function AddGos
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param
    (
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline=$True)]
        [string[]] $dbScript
    )
    process
    {
        $dbScript + "GO"
    }
}
```

If I call this like this:

```
("one", "two", "three") | AddGos
```

I get:

> one
>   GO
>   two
>   GO
>   three
>   GO

But if I call it like this:

```
AddGos("one", "two", "three")
```

Then I get this:

> one
>   two
>   three
>   GO

This is because when you run as a pipeline it breaks up my array and calls the `process` section for each entry in the array.  But when you call it normally it just passes in the array as a single object.

I can see a way to make this simple scenario support both, but when you start getting complex functions it could quickly get too complex to manage working for both scenarios.

**How this is normally dealt with in the Powershell world?**

Meaning to functions only support one way or the other?  Or is there some easy way to work around this that I am missing?  Or do function authors just work really hard to make it work either way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a `foreach` loop in the process block to handle both situations:

```
function AddGos {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param (
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline=$True)]
        [string[]] $dbScript
    )
    process {
        foreach ($item in $dbScript) {
            $item + "`r`nGO"
        }
    }
}

"one", "two", "three" | AddGos

AddGos "one", "two", "three"
```

Both calls will now give you the same result:

> ```
> one
> GO
> two
> GO
> three
> GO
> ```

P.S. you don't need the brackets around the array elements